# Add SSO (SAML Protocol) Login button to custom community login page

Tags: community, single-sign-on, saml

I would like to customize community login page. At the same time I have enabled SSO authentication for the community.

Is it possible to add "SSO Login button" to the custom login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answer by myself.
Go to the Setup -> Single Sign-On Settings
Open required SSO configuration and copy "Identity Provider Login URL" value.
Add regular apex:commandButton and action in the controller that returns Page reference to the "Identity Provider Login URL"

Comment: Did this really work?
I think it no longer works???
In our case there are potentially more parameters to inform the IP, of the SP.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193146&language=en_US) link where it says

> Login to Salesforce Org where the custom domain was configured as a
>   Salesforce Administrator and navigate to Setup>>Domain Management>>My
>   Domain. Once the "My Domain" page loads scroll down to the section
>   titled "Login Page Branding" and click edit. Next to the
>   "Authentication Service" section there are two check boxes Login Page
>   and IdentityConnect. Ensure the IdentityConnect checkbox is checked if
>   not check it and Save. Checking this box enables the Identity Connect
>   SSO (Single Sign On) button to show on the domain login screen.

Comment: In this case a SSO login button will be added to the My Domain standard login page. In my case we do not use My Domain functionality. We only use Communities.

Comment: This answer is for main login page for internal users.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use the getSamlSsoUrl from the AuthConfiguration class:

```
String communityUrl = '<Site URL of the Community>';
String startUrl = '/s';

Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = new Auth.AuthConfiguration(communityUrl, startUrl);

List<SamlSsoConfig> samlConfigList = [SELECT DeveloperName, Id FROM SamlSsoConfig WHERE DeveloperName = : 'SSO Unique Name'];
Id samlId = samlConfigList[0].Id;

String sso = Auth.AuthConfiguration.getSamlSsoUrl(communityUrl, startUrl, samlId);

system.debug(sso);
```